# In Blazor, how can I: 1: Preview a video which I upload on memory and 2: Upload it via an API?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have managed to **preview an image** and then **upload via http request API** with the code below:

```
// For Image Preview
async Task LoadImage(InputFileChangeEventArgs e) {
  var format = "image/jpg";
  var imageFile = await e.File.RequestImageFileAsync(format, 640, 480);

  fileStream = imageFile.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize);

  _fileName = e.File.Name;

  MediaStream = new MemoryStream();
  await fileStream.CopyToAsync(MediaStream);

  imageDataUri = $"data:format};base64,Convert.ToBase64String(MediaStream.ToArray())}";
}

// For API request, using multipart form data as I need to send a json object along with the image
protected async Task HandleValidSubmit() {
  _disabledSubmitButton = true;

  //create content headers
  var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
  content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");

  string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PostForCreation);

  content.Add(new StringContent(json), "fromRequestPost");
  MediaStream.Position = 0;
  content.Add(new StreamContent(MediaStream, (int)MediaStream.Length), "fromRequestMediaFile", _fileName);

  ////call to the server
  await PostService.CreatePost(content);

  _disabledSubmitButton = false;
}
```

My question is, **how do I achieve the same for a video file?** I want to be able to load the video in memory when the video is selected (like "LoadImage" function below), then pass it to the multipart API request upon submission (like "HandleValidSubmit" function below). Implementation of the API service is like a normal POST, so it's not included in the question as it is not relevant.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As far as I know, we couldn't directly preview the video in web application. But we could capture a image snap short for the video. Does this match your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It it possible. I cannot share the whole 'ready to go prod' code but following will get you started:

**js**

```
<script>
    function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
        var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
        var len = binary_string.length;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        return bytes.buffer;
    }

    function loadVideo3(base64, contentType) {
        var arrayBuffer = _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64);

        const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: contentType});
        var dataUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        var video = document.getElementById("videoTagId");
        video.src = dataUrl;
    }

</script>
```

**razor.cs**

```
    private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        isLoading = true;

        string contentType = "";
        string sourceB64 = "";
        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
        {
            try
            {
                contentType = file.ContentType;
                
                var fileSize = file.Size;
                var buffer = new byte[fileSize];
                await file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize).ReadAsync(buffer);
                
                sourceB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("File: {Filename} Error: {Error}",
                    file.Name, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        isLoading = false;

        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("loadVideo3", sourceB64, contentType);
    }
```

**razor**

```
<h3>Upload Files</h3>

<p>
    <label>
        Max file size:
        <input type="number" @bind="maxFileSize" />
    </label>
</p>

<p>
    <label>
        Max allowed files:
        <input type="number" @bind="maxAllowedFiles" />
    </label>
</p>

<p>
    <label>
        Upload up to @maxAllowedFiles of up to @maxFileSize bytes:
        <InputFile OnChange="@LoadFiles" multiple />
    </label>
</p>

<video id="videoTagId" controls="controls" width="400px" height="262px">
</video>
```

Please note that at the time of writing you have to convert byte array to base64 encoded string in order to pass it to JS function. With the release of .Net 6 there will no longer be this limitation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/byte-array-interop

> Blazor now supports optimized byte-array interop, which avoids
> encoding and decoding byte-arrays into Base64 and facilitates a more
> efficient interop process. This applies to both Blazor Server and
> Blazor WebAssembly.

As for a "native" blazor approach on how to preview video files - no idea :)

p.s. consider using ES modules for JS isolation and better resource management/disposal.